# Unable to convert the trigger from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, amazon-rds, plpgsql

I'm trying to convert the below trigger which is written Oracle to PostgreSQL:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "SCHEMA1".table1_ta
after delete
on table1
for each row
begin
    if :old.hid = 0 or :old.hid = -1
    then
        err.raise(-12345, 'Error Message');
    end if;
end table1_ta;
```

Below is the code which is getting generated as part of the schema conversion process of the AWS Schema Conversion Tool (SCT) but getting an error when I'm trying to apply it to the target PostgreSQL database.

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1_ta
AFTER DELETE
ON schema1.table1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema1.table1_ta$table();
```

Below is the error that I'm getting when AWS SCT is trying to create this trigger:

```
ERROR: function schema1.table1_ta$table(); does not exists.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) a trigger consists of two things in Postgres: the trigger **function** and the trigger _definition_. You need to write a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) first, then you can define the trigger

Comment: Thanks of the quick reply @a_horse_with_no_name. I'm not sure what do I need to specify within the trigger function I need to create. Could you please provide me with the code if possible as I'm not sure about it..

Comment: See docs here [plpgsql Trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [Oracle porting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-porting.html).